# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) showing in jQuery console( icon-1.png,icon-2.png,icon-3.png,icon-4.png)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a web application where I have to add jQuery version 3.2.1. I have not installed JQuery-UI. But in the console the following error message is showing 4 times:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Every error contains icon-1.png missing at the right side and gradually icon-2.png to icon-4.png.

I have clicked the link but it is showing under image directory 4 icons are missing but there is no image folder in my directory.

I have searched my problem but in many solution they are saying jquery-ui have missing image. But I have not installed jQuery-ui. So, none of the answer solved my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some of your plugins contains jqueryui most probably

Comment: Well what's your code and folder structure? If you go to the image urls and you get an error page, then you need to upload the items

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve This console error suggests that elements cannot be found at the specific path.